# Can Blazor be shipped as a local application?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, kestrel

I do not mean MAUI.

What I was thinking best experience for my audience would be simple service that would headlessly start server (kestrel?) so my application could be accessible for them through any browser on https://localhost:5000, just like for us when debugging.

Is this possible? If so, where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this,

but when you build your web-app, you already have it as an `exe` app.

So all you need is to find a way to package it with the DB Server you're using, configure the DB Server, and make sure that `dotnet` cli is installed, then finally create a `cmd` or `bash` file to run you're app using dotnet CLI.

```bash
dotnet run ./bin/myapp.exe
```